# nginx reverse proxy on different domain for different location with servername path

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two python django web applications A1 & B1. A1 runs on 8000 port and B1 runs on 8001 port on same server. A1 and B1 both are https and both are configured in same nginx and both works successfully.

Everything was working fine until a new requirement came.
We need to open https://A1/location1 as https://B1 but it should show https://A1/location1 in address bar.

Here what I have tried till now in my nginx's sites-available config.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name A1;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate /certificate/file/path;
    ssl_certificate_key /private/key/filepath;
location /location1/ {
proxy_pass https://loan.fundspi.com/;
 }
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    }
    location /media {
        alias /opt/A1/media;
        }
    location /static {
        alias /opt/A1/static;
    }

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name B1;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate /certificate/file/path;
    ssl_certificate_key /private/key/filepath;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
}
    location /media {
        alias /opt/B1/media;
        }
    location /static {
        alias /opt/B1/static;
    }

}
```

It opens https://B1 as https://A1/location1 what is expected but css js images do not load here. It tries to get css /js /images from path https://A1/static/js/file.js,  https://A1/static/css/file.css or  https://A1/static/img/file.png. Other site's js css img is not in static folder of project A1. They are present in static folder B1. That's why most of them 404.

I can not put static folder of B1 into static folder of A1. They are totally different. Some filenames are same but content is different. It will mess up the https site A1

There will be other locations too which will show content of B1's inner pages when user will open A1's inner pages but url will be of A1.

Please help me to write correct configuration file for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URLs that your `https://B1` generates for the static resources in your HTML.

The best way to do is to modify the application code for `B1` so that it uses `https://A1/location1/static` as the loading path for the resources instead of `https://A1/static`.

Another option that might work is to use `http_sub_module` to rewrite the HTML code from your proxy endpoint, so that all `/static` strings are replaced with `/location1/static`. This is somewhat dangerous though, because the replace might affect parts of code that you don't want to change.